# Sharepoint Document list edit

Tags: sharepoint, view

Is there anyway to edit a column in a document library? directly from the list view? So in Review Completed column below, just toggle the value rather than clicking on edit?

[image: are[][1]]

Comment: Is there a "Quick Edit" link in the command menu above the list? If it hasn't been disabled, that link allows you to edit all the visible fields as if they were cells in a spreadsheet.

Comment: yes quick edit is enabled but it shows up in detail pane, It does not allow to edit like cells in a spreadsheet. Also the detail pane shows the manage access bar, is there anyway to disable manage access? also is there anyway to rearrange the details pane?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this is a modern page, you may have a try [Field Customizer extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer).

Below is a sample:

- [React Toggle Field Customizer](https://delucagiuliano.com/sharepoint-framework-field-customizer-react-toggle)

[image]